# Ajax search post error

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax, pdo

I need help with two things. 
First: if I hit empty submit button. It should show me a error.
Second: If there is 0 results, it will give an error.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".search").click(function(){
        $.post("search.php", { keywords: $(".keywords").val() }, function(data){
            $("div#search").empty()
            $.each(data, function(){
                $("div#search").append("- <a href='#?id=" + this.id + "'>" + this.title + "</a><br>");
            });
        }, "json");
    });
});
```

--

```
$query = $db->prepare("SELECT `media`.`id`, `media`.`title` FROM `media` WHERE `media`.`title` LIKE :keywords");

$keywords = (isset($_POST['keywords']) === true) ? $_POST['keywords'] : '';

if (empty($keywords) === true) {
    $error = 'error';
    echo json_encode( $error );
} else {
    $query->bindValue(':keywords', '%' . $keywords . '%', PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $arr = array();
    $query->execute();
    while( $row = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC) ) {
        $arr[] = array( "id" => $row["id"], "title" => $row["title"]);
    }
    echo json_encode( $arr );
}
```

Comment: wat do you mean by ": if I hit empty submit button. "?

Comment: Maybe error message could help. Post it.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/Vpxrx/ my script

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK I have painstakingly recreated (jsfiddle does not let you copy/paste) this on my local machine. Your html/js code should look like this:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <input type="text" name="search" class="keywords">
        <input type="submit" name="submit" class="search">
        <div id="search"></div>
        <script>
            $(document).ready(function(){
                $(".search").click(function(){
                    $.post(
                        "search.php", 
                        { keywords: $(".keywords").val() }, 
                        function(data){
                              $("div#search").empty()
                          $("div#search").append(data);
                        }, 
                        "json"
                    );
                });
            });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

And for the PHP search.php page:

```
<?php
$keywords = (isset($_POST['keywords']) === true) ? $_POST['keywords'] : '';
if (empty($keywords) === true) {
    echo json_encode( "error" );
}
else {
    // run mysql commands
    // if resultset == empty
    // echo json_encode( "error" );
    echo json_encode( "actual data" );
}
?>
```

---

To parse json data in javascript do this:

```
$.post(
  "search.php", 
  { keywords: $(".keywords").val() }, 
  function(data) {
    $("div#search").empty();
    obj = JSON.parse(data);
    $("div#search").append(obj.id + " " + obj.title);
  }, 
  "json"
 );
```

Comment: Your php code does not check for a rowcount of any sort in that jsfiddle. Try getting rid of the php code (comment it all out) and then do a "echo json_encode('test');" and see if the PHP page returns this.

Comment: I have it working on my machine (you need to add db code as I dont have your database)

Comment: Have a look at my update, on how to parse json data and display it.

Answer (score 0):

try using `$(this)` instead of `this`